# List items are not refreshing when room data change

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, paging, lazycolumn

I have a lazy-column with a pager to show items using paging-compose 1 alpha 16 (latest).
I have some issues around.

1-> Every time an item is off the screen and back again it comes with a leak on the view like it was loading the entire data.

2-> When an item is updated on DB it changes its position on the list (as expected) but it is not show in the new data.

3-> The new data is only displaying correctly when the item goes out and get back to the screen.

I follow this tutorial to achieve the actual behavior https://medium.com/simform-engineering/list-view-with-pagination-using-jetpack-compose-e131174eac8e

My paging Size is of 50 items and i have leaks even with only 15. The views are simple. They have an image and 2 texts. And i tested without the image as well and still remains the problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the second point was that my text where custom AndroidViews and i was missing the update state parameter. For the other problems i still waiting for help